# Dell XPS 15 9550 - Bluetooth is not Working

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth-speaker

I've been trying pairing a bluetooth speaker with my laptop but it doesn't appear in the devices list, when I look at the bluetooth settings I see a list of *Unknown* devices.

I have the same problem if I try pairing my mobile on the laptop, while I can easily pair the speaker with my mobile.

- OS Ubuntu **20.04**
- Bluetooth device is **Broadcom Corp. BCM20703A1 Bluetooth 4.1 + LE**

I tried with restarting bluetooth on terminal running the following commands.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

Is there a way to find out what's the issue?

Comment: Does the Bluetooth work with other devices?

Comment: no it doesn't, e.g. it doesn't see my mobile either, but it sees other devices like a samsung TV

Comment: If so then not a problem with the specific peripheral mentioned in the question. Why then make it the focus of the question? Quite misleading. Please post the information re: the actual Bluetooth device (either `lspci` or `lsusb` should show which one you have) by [edit]ing the question and also rewrite it in order to reflect the actual problem instead of the red herring.

Comment: Please look at this page >> https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/bluez

Comment: Hello. It is nice that you found a solution BUT a solution that is only links is not really an answer you need the info that is in the links. Also please do not put a solution in the question. At the bottom of the question is a button that says answer your own question. The full answer needs to be entered that way so we can all see it.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted the problem out.

Bluetooth is not working because the firmware blob that is needed by Broadcom devices is not supplied by default, and it has to be supplied manually.

To do that you need to run the following commands.

```
wget https://memcpy.io/files/2017-10-28/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
sudo cp BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo chmod 0644 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
sudo reboot
```

I found the solution at the following link:

https://memcpy.io/fixing-bluetooth-on-the-xps-15-9550-on-ubuntu.html